# External Content Profile Pages in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-content-type, external-list

My institution is migrating to SharePoint online from an on-prem 2016 environment. One thing we currently rely on heavily is getting an ECT into the existing 2016 site and having a profile page for the item in question. This profile page is heavily customized using the old XML markup to have a nice layout.

Profile pages don't seem to be a thing in SPO. How do I create a page for an item on an external list so that I can create a nice layout in the modern experience?